# How do I get the node value of a specific node in a KendoUI treeView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-treeview

I need to get the node VALUE for the notificationId.

The name of the node is "ID" in the XML.

This is what I have right now:

```
$(function DeleteNotification (userId)
{
    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function()
    {
        debugger;
        var treeView = $('#treeview').data("kendoTreeView");

        $('#treeview').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function()
        {
            //this is what im trying to get but once i get to this point, nothing happens under debug mode
            var notificationId = treeView.text($("#ID"));

            alert(notificationId);

            //treeView.remove($(this).closest('.k-item'));
        });
    });
});
```

This line is not working:

```
var notificationId = treeView.text($("#ID"));
```

If you hover over the variable "treeView" you'll see this:

[image]

[image]

I need the circled value.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've been battling with this for the past 3 days and I cannot find the information I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
treeView.dataSource._data[2].notifications[0].ID
```

Comment: thanks this worked. YOU'RE THE MAN! I need to wait 10 mins before accepting your answer... grrr...

Comment: Neal, how would I implement this based on the loop I have in my OP? I want to run the "alert" function on all the checked nodes.